# RG flow of 4d Nonlinear Sigma model with $SU(n)$ target space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, sigma-models, wess-zumino-witten

Let's consider the 4d Nonlinear Sigma model with $SU(n)$ target space, without a topological term. The Lagrangian is
$$\frac{f^2}{16}\mathrm{Tr}(\partial_{\mu}U^{-1} \partial^{\mu}U)$$
where $U$ is a $SU(n)$ matrix, and $f$ is a coupling constant.
Dimensional analysis shows $f$ has mass dimension 1. This means under RG, $f$ will grow. I am puzzled what happens when we flow to deep infrared? Does it flow to a gapless fixed point with spontaneously symmetry breaking, and if so is it a CFT? Or does it flow to a gapped fixed point?

Comment: I think I would call this a 4-d non-linear U(n) sigma-model rather than a W-Z model.  W-Z really *requires* the topological term.  With a lattic eregulatorm there should be a critical coupling constant below   should flow to a gapless phase and above which it is disordered.

Comment: @mikestone thanks for the suggestion. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Because $f$ grows under RG, so it should flow to a disordered phase with only one ground state, with a finite energy gap to the first excited state. Is that right?

Comment: I only know for sure  the $d=2+\epsilon$ case. Then there is a UV fixed point at $f^{-1}= O(\epsilon)$ (asymptotic safety) that defines the transition.  See  Brezin, Eduard; Zinn-Justin, Jean (1976). "Renormalization of the nonlinear sigma model in 2 + epsilon dimensions". Physical Review Letters. 36 (13): 691–693.

Comment: @mikestone Thanks!

Comment: The 2D model is renormalizable and asymptotically free, but the 4D model isn't: it is a low energy effective theory.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, it is a low energy effective theory in 4d. But does it mean that it is not meaningful to ask its RG flow further toward IR?

Comment: All pions decouple at low momenta by virtue of derivative couplings— Adler zeros, not because f varies.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $$U = \exp\left(\frac1f\pi^a(x)\, T_a\right)$$ you see that this flows to a free massless theory of $N^2-1$ scalars. So yes, it flows to a CFT, namely the free theory.

The model OP writes is typically used to describe the symmetry breaking $\mathrm{SU}(N)_L\times \mathrm{SU}(N)_R\to\mathrm{SU}(N)_V$, of which $\phi^a$ are the Nambu-Goldstone bosons. However, that symmetry is broken already when you write down the sigma model, so there is no further symmetry breaking when going to the IR.